# Why does Java memory mapped buffer cause massive unexpected disk IO?

Tags: java, linux, performance, memory, file-io

I have written some Posix programs that make use of mapped file buffer. One simple scenario is to map a 1GB file into memory and fill up the entire file with content.

During the program execution there was little to no disk IO until `msync` or `munmap` call happens.

On exactly the same system, I wrote down the equivalent program in Java running on Oracle JDK 7, and noticed massive amount of disk IO activities throughout the entire program execution.

How is memory mapped file buffer implemented differently in JVM? And is there anyway to delay the massive IO activities?

The operating system is a Linux 3.2 x64.

Code:

```
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    long size = 1024 * 1048576;
    RandomAccessFile raf= new RandomAccessFile("mmap1g", "rw");
    FileChannel fc = raf.getChannel();
    MappedByteBuffer buf = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, size);
    for(long i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        buf.put((byte)1);
}
}
```

Comment: It could have something to do with the way you coded it. Without seeing the code, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: @NPE It is an obvious phenomenon if you have paid close attention to any of your mmap program. But I put up the code anyway.

Comment: You could write longs instead but all you need do it to touch every page (every 4 KB) to dirty the data faster. See the implementation for MappedByteBuffer.load(), all it does is read every 4 KB.

Comment: How much memory did your JVM have for the memory map?

Comment: @user2357112 The JVM doesn't limit the use of memory mapping.  You could set all your memory limits to a few MB and still map in a TB of memory.

Comment: @user2357112 What will limit your memory mapping is available address space for 32-bit JVM esp on Windows, your address space is very limited.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Limited memory will limit how much you can write before you need to do disk I/O, though.

Comment: @user2357112 Correct, but how much you can map, untouched is limited by the OS, e.g. for Windows 7 it is 192 TB, and Linux it is 256 TB.  On Linux this is a practical option as you have sparse files. eg. you can map in 8 TB but it doesn't use 8 TB of main memory or disk, if you don't touch those pages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Memory Mapping is entirely implemented in the OS.  The JVM has no say in how it is flushed to disk except by means of the `force()` method and the `"rws"` options when you option the file.

Linux will flush to disk based on the kernel parameters set in sysctl.

```
$ sysctl -a | grep dirty
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 10
vm.dirty_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 3000
vm.dirty_ratio = 20
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 500
```

These are the defaults on my laptop.  The ratio `10` means it will start writing the data to disk in the background when 10% of main memory is dirty. The writeback of 20% means the writing program will stop, untilt he dirty percent drops below 20%.  In any case, data will be written to disk after 3000 centi-seconds or 30 seconds.

---

An interesting comparison, it to memory map a file on a `tmpfs` filesystem.  I have `/tmp` mounted as tmpfs but most systems have /dev/shm.

---

BTW You might find this class interesting.  [MemoryStore](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Lang/blob/master/lang/src/main/java/net/openhft/lang/io/MappedStore.java) allows you to map any size of memory i.e. >> 2 GB and perform thread safe operation on it. e.g. you can shared the memory across processes. It supports off heap locks, volatile read/write, ordered write and CAS.

I have a test where two processes lock, toggle, unlock records and the latency is 50 ns on average on my laptop.

BTW2: Linux has sparse files which means you can map in regions not only larger than your main memory, but larger than your free disk space. e.g. if you map in 8 TB and only use random pieces of 4 GB, it will use up to 4 GB in memory and 4 GB on disk.  If you use `du {file}` you can see the actual space used.  Note: lazy allocation of disk space can lead to highly fragmented files which can be a performance problem for HDD.

Comment: @Howard It is also useful to see the essence of what Java is doing in one place instead of split across many classes which are not in `src.zip`

Comment: @Howard You can create slices of Bytes from a MemoryStore and either serialize/deserialize objects to it, e.g. as ObjectInput/Output, or map data structures to it.

Comment: I am in the process of building a SharedHashMap on top of MemoryStore (i.e. entirely off heap) which is concurrent, shared between processes, and can be replicated over TCP.